# react hooks useState consuming object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am not sure how to make it correctly so I can pass object to useState

```
const App = () => {
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({data: "", time: ""});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(apiUrl).then(response => {
      setWeatherData({...weatherData, data: response.data, time: timestamp});
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>{weatherData && <Weather data={weatherData.data} />}</div>;
};
```

when I do the same just with useState() and setWeatherData(response.data) it works fine but I would like to add the time

Comment: Why are you destructuring weatherData if you are overriding all its properties ?

Comment: And where does the ´timestamp’ come from ?

Comment: I show just part of my code and timestamp is const I used

Comment: Ok.

You don't need to destructure ```weatherData``` since you are overriding all its properties.

Is it intentional to run ```useEffect``` only once?

Comment: thanks, I will have to run it on interval but I removed dependency from array for now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
setWeatherData({
  ...response.data,
  time: timestamp,
});
```

P.S. Let me know if I understood you correctly.

**UPD**
Other option, if you need to access the current state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(apiUrl).then(response => {
    const timestamp = Date.now().timestamp;
  
    setWeatherData((prevWeatherData) => ({
      ...prevWeatherData,
      data: response.data,
      time: timestamp,
    }));
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: @jesetera if your issue is combining/flattening all the properties, then this is the correct answer.

Comment: thank you 
but I have parsing error when I try
` 
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(apiUrl).then(response => {
      setWeatherData((prevWeatherData) => {
  ...prevWeatherData,
  data: response.data,
  time: timestamp,
});
    });
  }, []);

`

Comment: maybe I have to check how to use previousState :/

Comment: @jesetera Sorry I've missed `(` and `)` in my response, I'll update it asap

Comment: @jesetera made an update, also created a fast codebox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bogdan-6uifd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you, looks like this is the right approach :) 
I just have to figure out how to access data 
when I pass it like this <Weather data={weatherData.data} time={weatherData.time} />
I can see time and data is an object 
but I am not able to access it with this code as before when I had just one response.data in useState
 const {
    name,
    sys: { sunrise, sunset },
    main: { temp, humidity, feels_like },
    wind: { speed, deg }
  } = data;

Comment: @jesetera it's really hard to help you without a proper codebox example where we can play with the code, I believe that you can find everything you are looking for in the official React docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const App = () => {
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchWeather () {
            const response =  await axios.get(apiUrl)
            setWeatherData({data: response.data, time: new Date().getTime()});
        } 
    
        fetchWeather()
    }, [weatherData]);

    return (
        <>
            {weatherData && <Weather data={weatherData.data} />}
        </>
    );
};
```